# Understanding abstract syntax tree generated in front-end phase of g++ compilation

Tags: c++, parsing, g++

I want to look at the syntax tree that is generated by g++ during compilation. Actually I want to understand the way how high-level C++ statements (especially initialization statements of classes and structure objects) are parsed by the g++ compiler and how the compiler do the semantic analysis of these constructs. My objective is specific for g++ only, and any general information regarding parsing and semantic analysis will not be helpful for me.

Looking at the g++ code, I could find out the data structure used inside and the different type of nodes it creates in files tree.def etc. I am wondering if there are good documentations available somewhere explaining this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: GCC uses two trees. For C++, it uses a tree similar to GENERIC but with C++ specific extensions. For the middle end where optimizations are done, it uses the GIMPLE tree. I recommend reading the [GCC internals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to GCC internals document mentioned above, there is a Mozilla project called [Treehydra](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Treehydra) that is a gcc plugin that will actually let you play with the GIMPLE ASTs using Javascript.  IMO this is a great way to learn about the GCC implementation.